# xcode 6 ios 8 recompile from 7.1 all container views have disappeared

Tags: xcode, storyboard

My app running in xcode 5 ios 7.1 has been recompiled in xcode 6 for ios 8.1 on new yosemite OS.

It's still running but all my container views have just disappeared from the storyboard. The definitions to the left of the storyboard are still present as are all the links.

When run in simulator there are also not showing

See below:

[image]

Defitions are still there:

[image]

And to clarify my actual question is how do I get these back without having to rebuild everything?

Answer (score 0):

turns out this is related to the container view having 0 width and 0 height. for some reason the migration process to xcode 6 thinks it's a good idea to make the container invisible.

Once you set to w/h the detail views will magically appear.

Other option that works but not ideal is to delete the segue between the container and the subview. Not ideal as it will disappear when you reconnect.

I'm assuming because the subview has inferred size that the 0/0 size of the container makes it also 0/0.

Comment: Not the same as my problem then... In my case setting the width/height parameters does not fix the issue.